# What does “do not get (too) vibed that something happened” mean? There is no clue in any dictionary

Tags: meaning, slang

I stumbled upon this construction: “don’t get (too) vibed”, but I couldn’t get what does it mean. And there is no dictionary that gives an explanation, as far as I can see. “Vibe” is a very special word suitable for use in many situations, but what exactly is “don’t get vibed that [something happened]”?

The first example:

> Though TBH I do not get vibed that he really enjoys playing it.

(Source: [forums.overclockers.co.uk/showpost.php?s=44516facf13f7525c31971c6e5693854&p=10689339&postcount=12726](http://forums.overclockers.co.uk/showpost.php?s=44516facf13f7525c31971c6e5693854&p=10689339&postcount=12726))

The second example:

> don't get too vibed that the MRI showed nothing, it's actually rather good!

(Source: [www.runnersworld.co.uk/forum/health--injury/mild-curiosity/185484.html](http://www.runnersworld.co.uk/forum/health--injury/mild-curiosity/185484.html))

Interestingly, the sources come from .uk sites. Is this a UK-specific phrase?

Comment: vibed = excited

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, UrbanDictionary did not give me such info: [www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=vibed](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=vibed). But now I have found another dictionary, it contains an entry for "vibed up" - this is a UK slang term...

Comment: The UD definition is not what you want, really... not sure what the definition you found was... you're more than welcome to answer the question yourself if you found the answer you seek. :)

Comment: I've found this in The New Partridge Dictionary Of Slang And Unconventional English ("vibed up = excited; in the mood [UK]"), but I still cannot be sure about the exact meaning...

Comment: I'm an American... I independently told you almost verbatim what the definition was from that dictionary and I promise, I didn't look it up first. I can understand your unsurety because the second example doesn't seem to mean "excited" but I think it could similarly mean "bothered" or "worried". Excited doesn't have to be positive.

Comment: *Vibe* is a slang form of "vibration" and refers (in AmE) to the general mood someone or something radiates.  You can see how *vibed (up)* could also mean "excited" (not necessarily in a happy way).